# How can i change the color of the field depending on its value in jasper reports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to set a specified color of the fields values if they are even numbers in jasper reports (jrxml), something like:

```
if $F{COLUMN_0}%2 == 0 ? setColor(RED) : setColor(blue)
```

Are there such thing in iReport?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know something called conditional styles in jasper reports?

[Refer this link](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-apply-conditional-formatting-your-text-fields)

Create conditional styles based on the field value and apply that style to the text field.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create one style in your report. Say evenColorStyle
2. Set the back color of your choice say red
3. Right click on newly created style.
4. Then select the conditional style
5. Set the back color say blue
6. Add this condition 
       new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue() % 2 == 0) 
   in your conditional style.
7. Add this style to text field.

You can change $V{REPORT_COUNT} depending of your requirement.